# Pararellize nested for loops over pandas rows

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a python code similar to this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('genelist.csv', names = ['ID', 'Tag'])

matrix = np.zeros((df.shape[0], df.shape[0]))

for element in range(df.shape[0]):
    for Element in range(element, df.shape[0]):
        matrix[element, Element] = distance(df['Tag'].iloc[element], df['Tag'].iloc[Element]
```

Where `distance()` is a complex function that calculates the distance between two tags. 
My dataframe is 8000 rows long and I need to speed up the process.
I started my script yesterday evening and **after 12 hours** it wasn't finished.
I was looking at the `multiprocessing` library but I do not know if it is possible since I have never used it.

The `distance` function looks like this:

```
def penn_to_wn(tag):
    """
    Convert between a Penn Treebank tag to a simplified Wordnet tag
    """

    if tag[0] == 'N':
        return 'n'

    if tag.startswith('V'):
        return 'v'

    if tag.startswith('J'):
        return 'a'

    if tag.startswith('R'):
        return 'r'

    return None

def tagged_to_synset(word, tag):
    """
    Returns synset of a couple of word, WordNet tag
    """

    wn_tag = penn_to_wn(tag)
    if wn_tag is None:
        return None

    try:
        return wn.synsets(word, wn_tag)[0]
    except:
        return None

def NS_sentence_similarity(sentence1, sentence2):
    """
    Compute the sentence similarity using Wordnet
    Distance(A, A) == 1,
    Distance(A, B) != Distance(B, A)
    """
    # Tokenize and tag
    sentence1 = pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence1))
    sentence2 = pos_tag(sentence2.split())

    # Get the synsets for the tagged words
    synsets1 = [tagged_to_synset(*tagged_word) for tagged_word in sentence1]
    synsets2 = [tagged_to_synset(*tagged_word) for tagged_word in sentence2]

    # Filter out the Nones
    synsets1 = [ss for ss in synsets1 if ss]
    synsets2 = [ss for ss in synsets2 if ss]

    score, count = 0.0, 0

    # For each word in the first sentence
    for synset in synsets1:
        # Get the similarity value of the most similar word in the other sentence
        try:
            best_score = max([synset.path_similarity(ss) for ss in synsets2])
        except:
            best_score = 0
        #print(best_score)
        # Check that the similarity could have been computed
        if best_score is not None:
            score += best_score
            count += 1

    # Average the values
    if count != 0:
        score /= count
    return score

def distance(sentence1, sentence2):
    """
    Compute the sentence similarity using Wordnet
    Distance(A, A) == 1,
    Distance(A, B) == Distance(B, A)
    """
    return (NS_sentence_similarity(sentence1, sentence2) + 
            NS_sentence_similarity(sentence2, sentence1)) / 2
```

Do you know any approach that could work?

Comment: How long does a single call to `distance` take? 1ms?

Comment: I haven't checked but it depends on the tags given. But not more than a few milliseconds

Comment: Can you show what `distance` looks like? Perhaps there's a way to speed it up.

Comment: Yes, I just edited the text

Comment: I'm going to guess your bottleneck is `wn.synsets`. The only ways to speed things up that I can see are either memoization (if your data repeats calls to `tagged_to_synset` with the same parameters) or multiprocessing as you suggested.

Comment: Do you often call `tagged_to_synset` with the same parameters? Simply adding a `@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128)` might significantly speed things up.

Comment: Looks like no explicit looping is needed in this case. So you should be able to speed this up by a factor of a few 1000 by using vectorized approaches.

Comment: Yes, basically `tagged_to_synset` given a word with a tag returns all the synonyms and since a lot of words are repeated I could try to memoize something.

With "no explicit lops" what do you mean?

Comment: Actually, I just checked, a single distance operation takes around 0.01 seconds to perform